# how to find iscsi initiator name in windows using cli

Tags: windows, powershell, iscsi

Is there a way to find out iSCSI initiator name on windows using CLI? It will be better if there is way to find it out using Powershell.

I have already looked at iscsicli.exe but it doesn't give me the information that i am looking for.

Comment: `iscsicli ListInitiators`

Answer (score 2):

Possibly it requires a newer version of Powershell but...

**(Get-InitiatorPort).NodeAddress**

That will give you the Initiator name.

Answer (score 1):

From Powershell, you can get it natively with Get-WmiObject:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class MSiSCSIInitiator_MethodClass).iSCSINodeName
iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:mandrews-pc.local
```

You can get it in a roundabout way from iscsicli.exe, but not in a format that's too helpful.  When you run iscsicli.exe interactively, it displays the initiator IQN in the prompt:

```
C:\Windows\system32>iscsicli
Microsoft iSCSI Initiator Version 6.1 Build 7601

[iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:your-pc.local] Enter command or ^C to exit
```

So if you've got powershell, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have powershell and you want get the iqn name through script, you can send the

cmd = "echo getiqn | iscsicli.exe". ( 'getiqn' is just a invalid input to iscsicli.exe to make it fail)

Now you have the iqn name in the cmd output.